# Using Increment operator with de-referencing in C

Tags: c, pointers, compilation, compiler-errors, dereference

To my function i get a void pointer, I would like to point to the next location considering the incoming pointer is of char type.

```
int doSomething( void * somePtr )
{
   ((char*)somePtr)++; // Gives Compilation error
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
Error[Pe137]: expression must be a modifiable lvalue
```

Is this an issue with the priority of operators?

Comment: *Which* compilation error ?

Comment: Error[Pe137]: expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Comment: `((char*)somePtr)` is not a variable, you can't inctement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cast does not yield an lvalue <sub>(see section 6.5.4 footnote 104 of C11 standard)</sub>, therefore you can't apply post increment `++` operator to its result.

[c-faq: 4.5](http://www.c-faq.com/ptrs/castincr.html):

> In C, a cast operator does not mean "pretend these bits have a different type, and treat them accordingly"; **it is a conversion operator, and by definition it yields an rvalue, which cannot be assigned to, or incremented with ++**. (It is either an accident or a deliberate but nonstandard extension if a particular compiler accepts expressions such as the above.)

Try this instead

```
char *charPtr = ((char*)somePtr);
charPtr++;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move the pointer to next then you can use:

```
*ptr++;
```

If you want to Change copy the pointer position to another variable then:

```
char *abc = (char*)(def + 1);
```

It really depends on your motive to do things

Comment: a note: you code implies gnu c compatibility. std didn't define addition to a void ptr.

Comment: I agree but he didn't ask for a std

Comment: The problem is I need to move to next location but this being a void pointer , I am trying to tell the compiler that I need to dereference it as a char pointer and increment. So the problem statement is while doing both of this together it gives a compiler error

Comment: the problem is op may not use gcc or any compatible ones. std compliant is default when environment or tool chain is not specified.